# Express angular and mysql

Tags: mysql, angularjs, express

i've tried to play around with express, angular, and mysql. connect to mysql is done, and even i can get the data json from the database. but i cannot access the data in angular. this is my simple code:

//database config:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : "localhost",
    user : "root",
    password : "toorape",
    database : "sakila" }); connection.connect();
```

// access rows. if i do: res.send(JSON.stringify(rows)); then will show the json in browser.
but wenn i do: res.render('index', { actor: rows }); then the browser shows nothing.

```
app.get('/users', function( req, res ){

connection.query('SELECT * from actor', function( err, rows, fields ) {

    if (!err) {

        console.log(rows);

        //get json
        //res.send(JSON.stringify(rows));
        res.render('index', { actor: rows });

    } else {

        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    }
});

//connection.end(); });
```

//makup

```
<div class="users"><div>
<p>{{actor.first_name}}</p></div>
```

did you guys maybe knows what i do wrong? thank you very much for any suggestions and idea.

Answer (score 0):

solved!!

is litle bit tricky, but is work good.

instead rendering index,

```
res.render('index', {actor:rows})
```

i change with json

```
res.json('index', rows);
```

and in controller, in success:

```
.success(function (data) {

    $scope.rows = data;
    console.log( data );

})
```

so i can access the database rows :)
in markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows">
<p>{{row.first_name}}</p></div>
```

in angular routes:

```
.when('/test', {

        templateUrl: '/templates/users.html',
        controller: 'UserController'
    })
```

in app.js

```
app.get('/test', function( req, res ){
res.render('index'); });
```

thanks.